# Pylance won't recognize an installed pip package

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, pylance

[There is a question with almost the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69407034/pylance-does-not-recognise-newly-installed-pip-packages), but I tried everything on there, and it doesn't fix it.

I tried to install the [ping3](https://pypi.org/project/ping3/) package using pip, and it is installed, but Pylance won't recognize it. I tried uninstalling and re-installing ping3, reloading vscode, and restarting vscode.

I want to create an issue on the Github repository, but it hasn't been active for a while.

Comment: Make sure you have activated the virtual environment you are using. If you aren't using virtual environments then start using them!

Comment: That fixed if for a bit, but it's happening again

Comment: What did you do exactly that fixed it before?

Comment: use a virtual enviroment

Comment: Okay, activate the virtual environment again. This is the basic solution - but there are many flavors of virtual environment (virtualenv, pyenv, conda and so on). Can you be more expansive on your question - it is hard to give advice going on so little information. What kind of virtual environment are you using? How did you activate it? Did you try activating it again? What resources have you find online and followed and what happened when you followed those instructions?

Comment: I'm using default venv (python -m venv project-venv), but it's okay, it somehow fixed itself overnight

Answer (score 0):

> Pylance won't recognize it

This may be caused by pylance.

You can try update or reinstall `Pylance` extension.

Comment: I did, but it didn't work. I think it's happening because Pylance refuses to check if the package is installed in a venv, and only checks if it's installed to the system

Comment: If you use a virtual environment, please check whether the package is automatically installed into the physical environment. You can use command `Python : select interpreter` to switch the interpreter